# Validation Rule: Voiding Order

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, business-logic, validation-rule

Kindly help me construct my validation rule here

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Status__c),
    OR(
       NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Draft")),
       ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Void")
 ))
```

Description of the rule: Order can only be voided if the status is draft.

Hope you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Does it not work? Are you getting an error? Off the top of my head, this validation rule looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I am thinking you just need to remove the `OR` statement, unless I am not understanding what you are asking.

As you have it, it will allow them to set the status to 'void', regardless of what the value was.

If you remove the `OR`, now you can only set the value of the picklist to 'void', if the prior value was 'draft'.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Status__c),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Draft")),
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Void")
)
```